# Unable to launch Chrome in remote webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I have set up 2 PCs as selenium hub & node.Now, I am trying to browse a URL in that node, from a console app that runs in the hub. But there is an error when initialising the browser.Both PCs run on windows 7.

```
//setting up the hub
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub");

//setting up the node
string Command1 = "/C cmdkey.exe /add:\\DES100 /user:abcd /pass:abcd123";
string Command2 = "psexec.exe \\DES100 -w D:\\Selenium java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role node -hub http://hubip:4444/grid/register";
Process.Start("cmd.exe", string.Format("{0} && {1}", Command1, Command2));

//open the browser

//ERROR AT BELOW LINE
IWebDriver NewDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://100.100.10.100:5555/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Chrome(),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

> ERROR The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://100.100.10.100:5555/wd/hub/session timed out after 180 seconds.

Comment: Also tried Method1 from http://blog.varunin.com/2011/10/running-tests-on-google-chrome-using.html. No luck.

Comment: What type of machine is the test going to be run on? (Windows? Linux?) Specifically what OS is this: 100.100.10.100

Comment: That was just a dummy id i gave. In my code, I give the actual URL of the node.Both machines run on Windows 7

Comment: I have updated my question with the new error. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You're string your grid on localhost:4444 and your webdriver URI is pointing to :5555

Its supposed to be:

```
IWebDriver NewDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://100.100.10.100:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Chrome(),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

Also make sure that your grid is launched by above line of code by opening your browser and typing

```
MachineIP:4444
```

Also you need to learn command bread up.
[image]

Learn more about it 
[selenium grid commands break ups](https://softwaretestingboard.com/qna/104/selenium-grid-commands-break-ups#axzz4wM3UEZtq)