# Unable to open selenium chrome driver from azure vm machine to my client machine? is that even possible?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, azure-virtual-machine

i have a angular project which triggers selenium Chrome-driver to open with help of c# API, it is working fine on my local machine. Now i have to deploy it on azure so my client can use in the same way too.

I tried and found out chrome-driver will only work on through azure VM-machine as it has some limitations. I purchased one azure VM and deployed my project there with chrome driver. it is working as a headless chrome-driver, i can see chrome driver is running in task manager but i cannot see the browser. Any help from anyone?

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));



driver.Url = "https://www.youtube.com";
```

Comment: How do you trigger it? call the exe file in azure vm, from another place?

Comment: ON LOCAL : I have a angular screen on button click i call an API which trigger chromedriver.exe

Comment: ON AZURE : I have a angular screen on button click i call an API which trigger chromedriver.exe which is already on my root folder i give path of it. Am i doing something wrong? do i have to use remote chrome driver?

Comment: If you run it on a remote machine, you should use remote chrome driver. Here is a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221291/unable-to-launch-chrome-in-remote-webdriver)